# Does not exist in current context error, but it should - ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    Writer.WriteBeginTag("li");
    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
            string myVar  = "even ";
    }
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        myVar += "third";
    }
    Writer.WriteAttribute("class", ""); // I want to use myVar here
    Writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    Writer.WriteEndTag("li");
}
```

I'm not all that familiar with .NET or C#. I get an error `The name "myVar" does not exist in the current context` on the second `myVar`. If I comment this line out, I then have a message `The variable "myVar" is assigned but its value is never used.` on the first `myVar`. I don't really understand how or why this would be out of context/scope.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myVar` only exists inside your `if`.

You need to move the declaration to the body of the loop.

Comment: Ok...that makes sense. Simple.

Answer (score 7):

You are creating the variable `myVar` in the scope of the first `if` statement, thus it isn't available in second one. You need to create it beforehand:

```
string myVar = "";
if(...)
{
  //use of myVar
}
if(...)
{
 //use of myVar
}
```